# EXCEL: Automatically populating cells from websites requiring a login and where the information is not directly stored in tables

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to write a VBA code in my excel file that would fetch data from my company's intranet site (which requires a login).

I am doing this as part of a company project and need the excel to auto fetch these fields (Numbers) from the portal.

I did some research and found relevant code that helps be automate the login process, but each field that I need to fill i.e Cells under Column C Row 1, need to first fetch the unique web link from Column A Row 1, so on and so forth.

```
Sub GetTable()
Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "http://severe-frost-552.heroku.com/login"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
    .login.Value = "dailydose"
    .Password.Value = "password"
    .submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "http://severe-frost-552.heroku.com/"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.all.Item("sampletable")

'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to teh sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
    Set clip = New DataObject
    clip.SetText "<html>" & ieTable.outerHTML & "</html>"
    clip.PutInClipboard
    Sheet1.Select
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
    Sheet1.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

The problem with the above code is that it can only fetch data from well defined tables on the website, but the data that I am trying to fetch is not defined under a div id and is just populated as text after appropriate spacing. eg. Also, it keeps returning the error that the client terminated the connection or IE didnt respond.

```
<div class="menuContent"><table width="100%"><tr><td width="50%"><h2 style="border-color: #2175BB;">Necessary persons</h2></td><td><h2 style="border-color: #2175BB;">Estimated time to complete</h2></td></tr><tr><td>
        **2**
    </td><td>
        **180 min**
    </td></tr>
```

The Bold text is what I need to fetch from the site into my excel. I don't care much for formatting. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `getElementsByTagName("td")` an option?

Comment: You say this is a company project and the portal an intranet portal? Would it be an option to access the *source data* of the portal directly, i.e. the database from which the portal pulls its data rather than the HTML output produced?

Comment: That wouldn't work since all the data in the sheet is using <td> tags.

@LocEngineer No, the database is not hosted separately. A company key user is directly updating the site and adding information as comments..

Comment: OK. Could he make his additions save to an accessible XML then? It's data. Company data. Should be made accessible to authorized entities if needed.

Comment: @LocEngineer Yes you are right, but since I am doing a project, it will be time consuming to request for a change in the method of updating the website. I was thinking more on the lines of finding the ''Estimated time to Completion'' keywords and then somehow making the code pick text after a specific number of characters. Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would not recommend this as one shall not parse HTML with Regex.
In this special case I think it is your best shot.

Set a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5, Replace the "txt" part from my Word macro and you should do fine:

```
Dim rex As RegExp
Dim matches As MatchCollection
Dim m As Match
Dim txt As String

Set rex = New RegExp
With rex
    .Pattern = "(Estimated time to complete)(.+?)(\<td\>)(.+?)(\<\/td\>\<td\>)(.+?)(\<\/td\>)"
    .MultiLine = False
    .Global = True
End With

txt = ActiveDocument.Content

Set matches = rex.Execute(txt)
For Each m In matches
    MsgBox "Necessary Persons: " & m.SubMatches(3)
    MsgBox "ETC: " & m.SubMatches(5)
Next m
```

Will that do the trick for you?