# VBA to extract data from a website with a login form

Tags: vba, excel

Given:

> A - website www.abc.com
>   B - case 
>   C - case details

I have a website (A) with a login form as 1st landing page.
After login, it directs to a page with a table populated with cases (B). (Maybe a dialogue box to authenticate the login access)
This table gets updated after each hour or so. When an update is done an object appears in the last column of the table (B).
When this object is clicked it directs the user to another page which contains data for that particular case reference (C).

Want to extract the data of the case reference (C) in the above process.

Ran some vba codes but got stuck in the middle part of the process.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'd recommend fleshing out your question to give a little more specific detail on what you've tried and exactly how you've run into problems. I don't know if it's close enough to your particular problem, but there's a similar sounding problem with VBA scraping and a login page covered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944819/excel-automatically-populating-cells-from-websites-requiring-a-login-and-where

Comment: Ran some vba codes but got stuck in the middle part of the process - Show us!